# Caanot fingd the eigen 3.3.9 sources download pointer

Tags: eigen3

I'am not able to find the proper link to download the Eigen 3.3.9 from gitlab repo (https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/tree/master).

May I ask you some hints ?

Cheers

Sylvain

Comment: The latest stable release (as of today) is 3.3.7. Check the Eigen homepage for download links

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need slicing features implemented in the 3.3.9 version . I cannot find this version in the git repo nor in the homepage. Some hints ?

Comment: You need the master branch for that

Comment: Many thanks for helping ! Cheers.